# MySQL script writing slow

Tags: mysql, optimization

I'm using php and the exec() function to run 2 MySQL script files one after another

The first file has approx 2k update statements (see below) in and is 114kb in size.

```
UPDATE table1 SET is_active = 1 WHERE id = 43;
```

The second has approx 15k update statements (see below) in and is 817kb in size.

```
UPDATE table2 SET is_active = 1 WHERE id = 12345;
```

The id column in table1 and table2 is a primary key so I would've thought this should be quite a quick update.

When I watch the MySQL Workbench dashboard for number of updates per second the first file runs at approx 80/s and the second 5k/s.

This means the smaller file with less updates is running much slower than the larger one.

Does anybody know if there is a logical reason for this?

Comment: Have you tried to run to run twice in a row the first script? How about the time of the second run?

Comment: I have now tried this and the query starts off at about 75 updates per second and then peaks with 800, I've tried this a few times (5) and get the same each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've realised that using an alternative query structure helps to speed this up.

```
UPDATE table1 SET is_active = 1 WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,...)
```

Works much quicker and reduces the script file size to 11kb from 114kb and also reduces running time from 40 secs to just under 2 secs

Comment: The reason why the IN works faster is that you are performing one transaction, not thousands.  In the normal configuration, there is one disk write per transaction, thereby limiting you to about 100 write statements per second.